# How to save data coming from a different MYSQL table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Good day, I have a form to add new registers to a table called "viajes", below, both tables:

A picture of my tables https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUHgJ.png

*agregar-viaje.php*

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

include('libreria/motor.php');
require ('connection.php');
require ('libreria/verificar-usuario.php');
$est=viajes::mostrar();
$viajes=new viajes();
if($_POST){
$viajes->NROVIAJE=$_POST['NROVIAJE'];
$viajes->IMO=$_POST['IMO'];

$querybuqueimo="select NOMBRE from buques as elbuque where IMO='".$_POST['IMO']."'";
$relabuqueimo=mysql_query($querybuqueimo);
$buquedeimox=mysql_fetch_assoc($relabuqueimo);
$buquedeimo=$buquedeimox["elbuque"];

$viajes->BUQUE=$buquedeimo;
$viajes->PTOPROCEDENCIA=$_POST['PTOPROCEDENCIA'];
$viajes->PAISPROCEDENCIA=$_POST['PAISPROCEDENCIA'];
$viajes->PTODESTINO=$_POST['PTODESTINO'];
$viajes->PAISDESTINO=$_POST['PAISDESTINO'];
$viajes->OPERACION=$_POST['OPERACION'];
$viajes->CARGA=$_POST['CARGA'];
$viajes->CANTIDAD=$_POST['CANTIDAD'];
$viajes->CHARTER=$_POST['CHARTER'];
$viajes->guardar();
    }
$result = mysql_query("SELECT NOMBRE, IMO FROM buques ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC");
$opcion=' ';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $opcion .= '<option value = "'.$row['IMO'].'">'.$row['NOMBRE'].' - IMO: '.$row['IMO'].'</option>';
}
$resultch = mysql_query("SELECT NOMBRECOMPANIA FROM clientes ORDER BY NOMBRECOMPANIA ASC");
$opcionch=' ';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultch)){
    $opcionch .= '<option value = "'.$row['NOMBRECOMPANIA'].'">'.$row['NOMBRECOMPANIA'].'</option>';
}
$maxnroviaje=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(NROVIAJE) as maximo from viajes");
$nroviajenew=mysql_fetch_assoc($maxnroviaje);
$nroviajex=$nroviajenew["maximo"];
$nroviajex++;

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Agregar Viaje</title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
<div class="form-group">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="NROVIAJE">Número de Viaje:</label>
    <input name="NROVIAJE" type="number" id="NROVIAJE" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" readonly value="<?php echo $nroviajex; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="IMO">Buque:</label>
    <select name="IMO" required id="IMO" class="form-control">
    <option value=" "> Seleccione el buque </option>
    <?php echo $opcion; ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="PTOPROCEDENCIA">Puerto de Procedencia:</label>
    <select name="PTOPROCEDENCIA" id="PTOPROCEDENCIA" class="form-control">
    <option value=" "> Seleccione un puerto de procedencia </option>
        <option value=" Aachen  "> Aachen </option>
        <option value=" Aalesund    "> Aalesund </option>
        <option value=" Aarhus  "> Aarhus </option>
        bla bla bla
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="PAISPROCEDENCIA">País de Procedencia:</label>     
    <select required name="PAISPROCEDENCIA" class="form-control">
      <option value="   ">Seleccione un país de procedencia </option>
        <option value=" Afganistán  "> Afganistán </option>
        <option value=" Akrotiri    "> Akrotiri </option>
        <option value=" Albania "> Albania </option>
        bla bla bla
      </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="PTODESTINO">Puerto de Destino:</label>
    <select name="PTODESTINO" required class="form-control" id="PTODESTINO">
    <option value=" "> Seleccione un puerto de destino </option>
        <option value=" Aachen  "> Aachen </option>
        <option value=" Aalesund    "> Aalesund </option>
        <option value=" Aarhus  "> Aarhus </option>
        bla bla bla
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="PAISDESTINO">País de Destino:</label>      
    <select required name="PAISDESTINO" class="form-control">
      <option value="   ">Seleccione un país de destino</option>
        <option value=" Afganistán  "> Afganistán </option>
        <option value=" Akrotiri    "> Akrotiri </option>
        <option value=" Albania "> Albania </option>
        bla bla bla
      </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Tipo de Operación:</label>
    <br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="OPERACION" value="CARGA" id="OPERACION_0" required>
      Carga</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="OPERACION" value="DESCARGA" id="OPERACION_1">
      Descarga</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="CARGA">Cargamento:</label>
    <select name="CARGA" required id="CARGA" class="form-control">
    <option value=" ">  Seleccione el cargamento     </option>
    <option value=" 150N    ">  150N     </option>
<option value=" 150N/CHEVRONTEXACO  ">  150N/CHEVRONTEXACO   </option>
<option value=" 150N/SHELL  ">  150N/SHELL   </option>
bla bla bla

    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="CANTIDAD">Cantidad (BBLS):</label>
    <input name="CANTIDAD" type="number" required id="CANTIDAD" min="1" class="form-control">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="CHARTER">Charter (Cliente):</label>
    <select name="CHARTER" required id="CHARTER" class="form-control">
    <option value=" "> Seleccione el charter (cliente) </option>
    <?php echo $opcionch; ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="Enviar" id="Enviar" value="Enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
  </p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code of my form and I have managed to shoe a list of every vessel and her IMO in "Select IMO", however, I'm trying to find a way to, when pressing the submit button, both IMO and its related buque get saved in the viajes table, without having to add "buque" in any way in the form.

The way I'm doing things, a new register is being created in the "viajes" table with the rest of the data, but "buque" field remains blank and I get the following PHP error: *Notice: Undefined index: elbuque in C:\xampp\htdocs\agente-nav-online\agregar-viaje.php on line 16*

Many thanks beforehand four your help.

Comment: First of all, why are you mixing procedural style with object-oriented style? Secondly, **stop using mysql_* functions**. Seriously, it's 2018 and people still use those? Please, get PHP 5.6+ and start using parameterized statements with MySQLi or PDO. Thirdly, you do know that there is a Spanish version of StackOverflow, right? And last but not least, the PHP error is very clear, the index is undefined. I'll save you the theory lesson: `select NOMBRE from buques as elbuque` is **wrong**. You should do `SELECT NOMBRE AS elbuque FROM buques`. I suggest you start learning how to debug your code.

Comment: @Zeke many thanks for your help. Styles are just different approaches to do thigs, aren't they?. I've been told about using mysqli over mysql, I'm just trying to solve problems for a small course I'm taking on PHP and MYSQL basics. I know for a serious project  should use safer tools as mysql_* functions are deprecated. I know SO en español exists, I also wanted to post it here to get more possible answers.

Comment: It's not a good idea to mix those styles. Stick to just one of them. They're different paradigms (you should know this if you're studying Engineering). If you think that using deprecated things means to learn the basics, then you're wrong. Do things the right way from the ground up, or else you'll develop bad coding habits and you'll get more confused in the future. Also, think about this: if many people have told you to use MySQLi, then there must be a good reason for it. Listen to them. Just do it. And one more thing: don't use uppercase letters for your columns. Just don't.

Comment: Anyway, did that SQL change solve it? If it did, I’ll just add the answer so we can close this question as solved.

Comment: Yes @Zeke, the SQL solved my issue. Thanks a lot. You can post the answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following `error_log` line:

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: elbuque in C:\xampp\htdocs\agente-nav-online\agregar-viaje.php on line 16

And this part of the code:

```
/* 13 */ $querybuqueimo = "select NOMBRE from buques as elbuque where IMO='".$_POST['IMO']."'";
/* 14 */ $relabuqueimo = mysql_query($querybuqueimo);
/* 15 */ $buquedeimox = mysql_fetch_assoc($relabuqueimo);
/* 16 */ $buquedeimo = $buquedeimox["elbuque"];
```

The notice occurs on line 16, indicating that the index `elbuque` is nonexistent in the `$buquedeimox` array.

As we can see on line 13, the SQL syntax is wrong, where the following:

```
select NOMBRE from buques as elbuque where IMO='".$_POST['IMO']."'
```

Should actually be:

```
select `NOMBRE` as `elbuque` from `buques` where `IMO`='".$_POST['IMO']."'
```

#### Further comments

> Do **not** use **`mysqli_*`** functions since these are deprecated and insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO with parameterized statements instead. This will also prevent SQL injections.

Stick to object-oriented style or procedural style, but don't mix them unless entirely necessary. I personally suggest object-oriented style, this paradigm improves your code's readability, efficiency, efficacy, modularity, and ultimately makes your application more maintainable.